# Unable to publish Shiny R data table

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, publish, htmlwidgets

This is the first project I design with RStudio and Shiny. Thus I believe there is some trivial issue I cannot understand yet.

I am attempting to publish two large tables as a Shiny R App online, using shinyapps.io. The code works fine locally but the tables will not show online when published. See below

https://myrmeco-fox.shinyapps.io/Transcriptome_Table/

My scripts as follows:

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Summary of de novo assembly annotations",
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel("Contigs", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
      tabPanel("Isotigs", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  Contigs<-reactiveValues(Contigs_Table=read.table("Data/annotations_expanded_CONTIGS.txt", header= TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, na.strings = c("", "---NA---"), nrows=7467, colClasses="character", quote=""))
  class(Contigs_Table$Length)<-"numeric"
  class(Contigs_Table$Cys)<-"numeric"
  Isotigs<-reactiveValues(Isotigs_Table=read.table("Data/Annotation_summary_expanded_ISOTIGS", header= TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, na.strings = c("", "---NA---"), nrows=12538, colClasses="character", quote=""))
  class(Isotigs_Table$Length)<-"numeric"
  class(Isotigs_Table$Cys)<-"numeric"
  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable(Contigs_Table, options = list(pageLength = 5))
  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable(Isotigs_Table, options = list(pageLength = 5))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Summary of de novo assembly annotations",
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel("Contigs", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
      tabPanel("Isotigs", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2"))
    )
  )
)
```

SERVER

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  source("Data.R")
  class(Contigs_Table$Length)<-"numeric"
  class(Contigs_Table$Cys)<-"numeric"
  class(Isotigs_Table$Length)<-"numeric"
  class(Isotigs_Table$Cys)<-"numeric"
  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable(Contigs_Table, options = list(pageLength = 5))
  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable(Isotigs_Table, options = list(pageLength = 5))
}
```

DATA

```
Contigs<-reactiveValues(Contigs_Table=read.table("Data/annotations_expanded_CONTIGS.txt", header= TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, na.strings = c("", "---NA---"), nrows=7467, colClasses="character", quote=""))
Isotigs<-reactiveValues(Isotigs_Table=read.table("Data/Annotation_summary_expanded_ISOTIGS", header= TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, na.strings = c("", "---NA---"), nrows=12538, colClasses="character", quote=""))
```

I have followed instructions from several discussions, such as adding the files to a subfolder (they are uploaded as well) and using reactiveValues. I have slightly changed syntax (with and without dot, etc) and still nothing worked.

Comment: Also if anyone would know of a better platform to publish this type of material? This one is paid!..

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: @user8383881 None. As described: the tables render fine locally but not in the server. I believe you can see in the link. I think there is a trivial issue in indexing the files correctly but I have tested all I could to no avail.

Comment: what about putting "/" in front of Data? I assume your data is in this Data subfolder?

Comment: OMG I *knew* this was something silly ! Actually I did change the syntax slightly, as I said, by adding either "./" or "/" to my script, but apparently I was doing that in the main file but *not* in the Data file. Thanks!! Can you make this into an answer so I can reward you? Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: BTW I think if you test my link now, you should see the tables displaying correctly. Please confirm?

Comment: Confirmed, 2 tables visible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) 
what about putting "/" in front of Data? I assume your data is in this Data subfolder?

Comment: Thanks! I know it looks obvious, but I had tried before adding "/" or "./" to Data script however it did not work. In the end I realised I had to add "./" to *both* the **main** script file and **Data** to be uploaded in deploying. Then it worked.

Comment: Please also let me know if you'd know of a more accessible alternative to this interface. In a shiny server I am limited to 24 mins per month of display, as a free user. I think a similar interface would be offered in html (e.g. using plotly) but I could not design it.